# Is there a text-based Windows Firewall Configuration?

Tags: firewall, windows-firewall, text

In Linux, you can use iptables to store/load your iptables based firewall configuration, but in Windows it appears to me that it's all GUI based, which means you can't store / track the changes you've made to it.

So, does Windows have an equivalent text-based firewall configuration, one in which you can export it, modify it and reload it?

Comment: I know there's `netsh` but that's getting a bit dated no?

Comment: **So, does Windows have an equivalent text-based firewall configuration, one in which you can export it, modify it and reload it?** - You can manage the Windows Firewall with netsh or with Powershell.